# Не удается получить ymaps в vue js

Tags: vue.js, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Пытаюсь получить ymaps как указано в документации

```
import { loadYmap } from 'vue-yandex-maps';
    async mounted() {
        const settings = { lang: 'en_US' };
        await loadYmap(settings);
        console.log(ymaps); // здесь доступен весь функционал ymaps
      },
```

выдает ошибку

```
error 'ymaps' is not defined no-undef
```

Comment: получилось ли? возникла такая же проблема.

Answer (score 1):

В моём случае проблема была решена с помощью добавления асинхронной подгрузки *loadYmap* в mounted. Т.о. после такой подгрузки переменная *ymaps* становится доступной сама по себе. Т.е. получилось как-то так:

```
async mounted() {
  await loadYmap({
    debug: true
  });
}
```